PostScan service like DeutschePost for letters delivered by Citipost?
I know that Deutsche Post offers a PostScan service https://www.deutschepost.de/de/p/postscan.html where they can open letters, scan them and save files online for 15 euros/month.
But all the important letters from the tax office and migration office that I received by mail are sent by the company Citipost, which is not part of Deutsche Post.
I wonder if Citipost has the same PostScan service as Deutsche Post that I can subscribe to?
Does anyone have experience with this service from Citipost?
Thanks,

Citipost is a brand. There are at least a dozen different companies that utilize this brand. They serve different areas, charge slightly different fees and offer different ranges of services. Therefore you need to state in your question which specific Citipost company you refer to, which location you are at.

@KaiBurghardt thank you, I found that the branch is Nordwest and I contacted them and they said there is free of charge mail forwarding service.

Well, I guess you could redirect your mail to a P. O. Box belonging to a digitization company you have concluded an agreement with so you receive a digital copy instead of the original, yet this does not work for mail bearing a do not forward postal note.

@KaiBurghardt your idea looks interesting. Do you know which mails normally are sent with "do not forward" postal note? Currently, I'm only interested in mails from Migrationsamt/Finanzamt.


[…] I wonder if Citipost has the same PostScan service as Deutsche Post that I can subscribe to? […]

As of August 2024 Citipost Bremen does not offer a similar service, nor do they cooperate with a company that renders such services.

[…] I found that the branch is Nordwest and I contacted them and they said there is free of charge mail forwarding service.

Using their free of charge mail forwarding service you can redirect any mail delivered by Citipost Bremen to the P. O. Box of a digitization company you have concluded an agreement with.
Note that by delivering mail to the P. O. Box Citipost Bremen has fulfilled its part of the shipment agreement.
If you want to obtain the original, a new agreement has to be concluded (i. e. fresh postage stamps).
A quick internet research shows that competing digitization companies are cheaper by one or two euros per month, but charge (a lot!) extra for remailing the original to your home address.
By default mail is disposed.
DPAG PostScan at least stores and forwards any mail once a month without additional charges for that.

[…] Do you know which mails normally are sent with "do not forward" postal note? […]

Germans usually do not endorse any mail as unforwardable.
Either it is ignorance – snail mail being considered a bit of an antique service so they do not bother familiarizing with all the recognized endorsements – or they sincerely do not want to cause any additional delays in carriage.

Companies you owe money to may always indicate do not forward simply because it is more difficult to enforce a claim if you do not know a ladungsfähige Anschrift.
By receiving returned undelivered mail you can conclude “uh oh, that customer must have moved (without telling us).”
For example the Kölner Verkehrsbetriebe (Cologne Public Transportation Authority) mailed me almost everything in this fashion.
Authorities and agencies generally keep their mail forwardable.
The laws do not dictate that messages have to be taken notice of at your registered place of residence.
The government has other means to ruin your day, in particular choosing an unreliable carrier that is known to lose mail once in a while (but is 2 ct cheaper than the reliable competitor) comes to mind.


thanks, I ended up using the free mail forwarding from Citipost to my relative address in another state In Gemrnay and I can access my letters their.
